# Jupyter Notebook - ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to make a program where a the program asks the user for a number and keeps asking until a blank line is entered. Then, it should print out how many even numbers there are. Now the only problem is that every I enter a blank  line it gives me this error: `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''`. Can you give the solution?

```
number = int(input('Enter your number: '))
count = 0
even = []

while number:

    even.append(number)
    if number %2 == 0:
        number = int(input('Enter your number: '))  
    else:
        number = int(input('Enter your number: '))

number = int(input('Enter your number: '))
for nums in evens:
   count+=1
   print(f'Your even numbers are: {nums} ')
```

Comment: Do `while True` with `try/catch` block. You always try to parse the input, so `while(number)` won't work (it will break only at `0`), as empty input is not a number and will throw an error. That's why you should `catch` that error and then `break` out of the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if user provided number. Casting any string to int can cause ValueError

```
number = input('Enter your number')
if number.isdigit():
    number = int(number)
else:
    print('Please provide a correct number value')
```

Comment: Where do I put this syntax?

Comment: Try out it instead of your first line

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code:

```
number = input("Enter Number:\t")
my_list = []
while True:
    if number.isdigit():
        my_list.append(int(number))
        number = input("Enter Number:\t")
        continue
    elif number.isspace():
        print()
        print("The Even Numbers are:\t")
        print(*[var for var in my_list if var%2==0])
        break
    else:
        print("Wrong input Enter number or press space. Start from beginning")
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

```
isExit=False
str_number=input('Enter your number: ')
if str_number.isnumeric():
    number = int(str_number)
else:
    isExit=True
count = 0
even = []

while not isExit:
    if number %2 == 0:
        even.append(number)
    str_number=input('Enter your number: ')
    if str_number.isnumeric():
        number = int(str_number)
    else:
        isExit=True
if even:
    for nums in even:
        count+=1
        print(f'Your even numbers are: {nums} ')
else:
    print('No even numbers')
```

Hopefully this will work according to your need